# How to input command lines inputs to program in debugger as to be able to observe what happens with the input at every steps?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

I've being using visual studio for a year and there is still something that I still do not understand. How do I effectively use the debugger feature in it? Especially for C++

Here the code that I want to debug:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;

//sort methode
void swap(long long int* a, long long int* b) { 
    long long int t = *a; 
    *a = *b; 
    *b = t; 
} 
int partition (vector<long long int> vector, long long int left, long long int right) { 
    long long int pivot = vector[right];  
    int i = (left - 1);   
   
    for (int j = left; j <= right- 1; j++) { 
        if (vector[j] <= pivot) 
        { 
            i++;  
            swap(&vector[i], &vector[j]); 
        } 
    } 
    swap(&vector[i + 1], &vector[right]); 
    return (i + 1); 
}  
void quickSort(vector<long long int> vector, long long int left, long long int right) { 
    if (left < right) { 
        long long int pivot = partition(vector, left, right); 
 
        quickSort(vector, left, pivot - 1); 
        quickSort(vector, pivot + 1, right); 
    } 
} 
//end sort

//mainMethod
void maxoddValue(vector<long long> nVector, vector<long long> kVector, int n){
    //declare the 4 necessary vectors
    vector <long long> largestEven;
    vector <long long> largestOdd;
    vector <long long> smallestEven;
    vector <long long> smallestOdd;

    long long cur_val = - 1;
    //largestEven
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--){
        if (nVector[i] % 2 == 0){ //if value is even
            if(nVector[i] < cur_val){ // and the value is smaller than the 
                smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);
            } else { //if the value is larger than cur_val,update it
                cur_val = nVector[i];
                smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);
            }
        } else { //if value is odd
            smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);            
        }
    }
    //largestOdd
    for (int i = n - 1; i >= 1; i--){
        if (nVector[i] % 2 != 0){ //if value is odd
            if(nVector[i] < cur_val){ // and the value is smaller than the cur_val
                smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);
            } else { //if the value is larger than cur_val,update it
                cur_val = nVector[i];
                smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);
            }
        } else { //if value is even
            smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);            
        }
    }

    //smallestEven
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (nVector[i] % 2 == 0){ //if value is even
            if(nVector[i] > cur_val){ // and the value is smaller than the cur_val
                smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);
            } else { //if the value is larger than cur_val,update it
                cur_val = nVector[i];
                smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);
            }
        } else { //if value is odd
            smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);            
        }
    }

    //smallestOdd
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if (nVector[i] % 2 != 0){ //if value is odd
            if(nVector[i] > cur_val){ // and the value is smaller than the cur_val
                smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);
            } else { //if the value is larger than cur_val,update it
                cur_val = nVector[i];
                smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);
            }
        } else { //if value is even
            smallestEven.push_back(cur_val);            
        }
    }

    //testing purpose
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        cout<< largestEven[i] << " " << largestOdd[i] << " " << smallestEven[i] << " " << smallestOdd[i] << "\n";
    }

}


int main(long long int argv){
    //driver:
    long long int a;
    long long int b;
    long long int n; 
    long long int k;
    //1st input
    cin >> n;
    vector<long long int> n_values;
    //2nd input
    while (n_values.size() < n){
        cin >> a; 
        n_values.push_back(a);
    }

    vector<long long int> k_values;
    //3rd input
    cin >> k;

    vector<long long int> reverse_nValues;
    //4th input
    while (k_values.size() < k){
        cin >> b;
        k_values.push_back(b);
    }
    quickSort(n_values,0,n - 1);
    reverse(n_values.begin(),n_values.end());
    maxoddValue(n_values,k_values,n);

}
```

I have being encountering segmentation fault: 11 (I think its something about indexes), but I do not know where am I not doing correctly. As shown in the code, I have input the codes inside my terminal, but I want to be able to do that in the debugger as well. I've searched online but could not really find a way to do it.

My launch.json file is as below;

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "g++ - Build and debug active file",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}/${fileBasenameNoExtension}",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "lldb",
            "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: g++ build active file"
            
        }
    ]
}
```

The input sample that I have is for instance:

```
4 4 2 1 3 3 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you are using Visual Studio (VS) I am assuming it is in Windows.
- If you want to effective use VS first create a project either in the VS startup screen (Create New Project) or using File->New->Project if already inside VS.
- In your case create an 'Empty c++' Project and specify the project name and location in Configure screen.
- In Solution Explorer window, right click and add either your existing c++ file or create a new c++ file and copy paste your code.
- With drop down solution configuration choose 'Debug'.
- From main menu 'Build' your solution.
- From main menu 'Debug->Start Debugging' or use F5
- You need to place breakpoint on a line just click to space left of line (try clicking at various places left of the line and a red dot will appear as a breakpoint)
- While Debugging various information windows will open up like current state of variables, value of variables on a line, call stack etc.
- If exception check the 'call stack' window and it will show you the flow (lines) of program leading to exception. Selecting previous lines it will show the state leading to exception.
- Key shortcuts for VS debugging: F5 start, F11 step in, F10 step over, etc
- Google VS debugging for more info.

Hope this helps :) or can give further clarification.

Comment: oh sorry, I just looked and I forgot to add that I was not using visual studio, but visual studio code, so the OS that I am using is MacOS. Do you happen to know how to do it on that as well? Thank in advance and sorry for the mis-information.

Comment: Nope! not worked with VSCode for code debugging.